# Database does not exist - Docker/PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker

So I been working around with Springboot and am trying to setup a PostgreSQL database in a docker container. I have the following bash script to create the container:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail
which psql > /dev/null || (echoerr "Please ensure that postgres client is in your PATH" && exit 1)

mkdir -p $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres
rm -rf $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres/data

docker run --rm --name pg-docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=... -e POSTGRES_DB=dev -d -p 5432:5432 -v $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql postgres
sleep 3
export PGPASSWORD=...
psql -U postgres -d dev -h localhost -f schema.sql
psql -U postgres -d dev -h localhost -f data.sql
```

However I get the error `psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "dev" does not exist`.

I ran `docker exec -it pg-docker psql -U postgres -c "\l"` from the Git Bash terminal inside my directory. I got this:

[image]

As of right now, here are my files:

[image]

and here is my application.properties:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils=debug
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.jpa.database=postgresql
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dev
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=...
```

If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: are you sure that `sleep 3` is enough time to start the container and have the postgresql service working? have you tried to manually execute the `psql -U postgres -d dev -h localhost -f schema.sql` command after you were able to validate that `dev` database exist running the command from the inside of the container?

Comment: @GastónSchabas I have manually tried to execute the line after the script ran, same error. I tried chaning it to `sleep 10`, same error. I even have Docker Desktop open and I watch the container get created in front of my own eyes, yet same error

Comment: When you run the docker command, what messages/logfile do you get out?

Comment: I just executed the same docker command you are using to create the container with the database **deb** and I was able to connect to the container from the outside. Not sure what is happening with that level of details. You would need to add more debugging details. Also you can try to run your script in another machine, or inside a CI/CD pipeline tool

Comment: @GastónSchabas Assuming u mean the database **dev**, I execute the above bash script in a Git Bash environment. By this I mean I go to the directory of my bin folder (as seen in the file structure above) in file explorer, right click, and click "Git Bash here". Then I run `./start_postgres.sh` and get that error

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Solution: changed the -p argument in the docker command line to `-p 5433:5432`. Also changed the last 2 execution lines:

```
psql -U postgres -d dev -h localhost -p 5433 -f schema.sql
psql -U postgres -d dev -h localhost -p 5433  -f data.sql
```

Why was port 5432 breaking everything? I have no clue either. It may have to do with the fact that I have a local instance of Postgres installed and running `psql` connected to the local instance instead of the Docker container.

If my explanation seems wrong, please correct me in the comments as I am still learning :)

Comment: That make sense. Sounds like port `5432` (the default one for postgres) was already being used by your local postgres installation in the host machine. I think there should be some error message saying `address already in use` when you try to start the docker container for postgres. If you try to run the same command without the parameter `-d` you should see it in the console. The article [Docker Error Bind: Address Already in Use](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/docker-address-already-in-use) from **Baeldung** should help you with that.

Comment: Thanks for reply @GastónSchabas. I'll be sure to run my containes without -d in the future at first for debug options